# Not able to access the variable equivalent of the eloquent method

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following eloquent method in my application:

```
public function votes() {
        return $this->morphMany(Vote::class, 'votable');
    }
```

and when I try to access the variable votes (as laravel has dynamic properties) like `$userVote = $this->votes->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();`, I get the following error:
`"Call to a member function where() on integer"` and when I use `dd($this->votes)` it displays 2. I am all confused.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a get mutator for `votes`? A method named `getVotesAttribute()` on that model? Laravel will run that if you do instead of accessing the relationship like you're trying to do.

If this is the case, or even if not, you can still access the relation through the query builder by calling the method instead of the attribute. In fact through the query builder won't load all of the `votes` if you're only looking for one. The way you wrote it would load all the votes and then filter the returned collection.

Using the query builder you could do:

```
$this->votes()->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
```

Comment: I should be able to access the property ```votes```, shouldn't I? I have already defined the relationship votes() in the class. This is mentioned on the laravel documentation as well. **Once the relationship has been defined, we can access the collection of comments by accessing the  comments property. Remember, since Eloquent provides "dynamic properties", we can access relationship methods as if they were defined as properties on the model.**

Comment: You are able to if you don't have an attribute named `votes` and no get mutator named `getVotesAttribute()` as these will return before the model resolves the property as a relation. `getAttribute()` is called when the attribute you're accessing isn't directly accessible on the model. You can see it here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L295